# routing in angularjs with nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am building an application with AngularJS 1.7 for the frontend and using NodeJS for the backend. I am facing troubles implementing the routes. What I'm trying to do is set up routes in angular as well as in Node. 
For eg:
I have '/contacts' route in angular which server the index page for me. It works just fine.
Now when i want to load data into the page, I'm trying to make a http request to '/contacts' which should ideally get me data from the Node backend. I am actually confused on how the routing will work in this case. Will there be any conflicts?

Node code :

```
const contacts = require('./routes/contacts');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use('/contacts',contacts);
```

I have routing set up in contact file which i have included on top.

Angular code:

```
$routeProvider.when('/contacts',{templateUrl:'views/contacts.html',controller:'contactsController'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide whole code, maybe the problem is in the beginning of your configuration. I did work with angularJs and I have a simple project on my github which may help you how to manage routes.

See [github-angularjs-springboot-project](https://github.com/9uilherme/api_enterprise_sale/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/js/app.js).